# What activation functions are better for what problems?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, activation-functions

I’ve been reading about neural network architectures. In certain cases, people say that the sigmoid "more accurately reflects real-life" and, in other cases, functions like hard limits reflect "the brain neural networks more accurately".

What activation functions are better for what problems?